# if else loops and repeat until loops doesn't work with algorithm package

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

**code:**

```
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\caption{Adaptive Random Search}\label{algo_ARS}
\State define the probability of local search as $P_s$ and global search as 1 - $P_s$
    \Repeat
    \State generate a random number r(0,1)
        \If{r \leq $P_s$} 
            \State local search is selected
        \Else
             \State global search is selected 
    \Until{$X_{ARS}$ is accepted}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

**output:**
[image]

My code for writing a pseudocode doesn't work. I cant get until part as an output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think, there is an `\EndIf` missing in your code (after the if statement, before `\Until`). It would be good if you could extend your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that also shows the packages you are using.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd change `1 - $P_s$` to `$1 - P_s$` and also write `$r(0,1)$` and `$r \leq P_s$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which packages you use exactly, but you are probably missing an `\EndIf` command that closes the nested if statement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\caption{Adaptive Random Search}\label{algo_ARS}
\State define the probability of local search as $P_s$ and global search as $1 - P_s$
    \Repeat
        \State generate a random number $r(0,1)$
        \If{$r \leq P_s$} 
            \State local search is selected
        \Else
             \State global search is selected
        \EndIf
    \Until{$X_\mathrm{ARS}$ is accepted}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I haven't realized it. Thank you so much!